# select background-image of div value with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get the css value of the background-image of some div, but i don't know how.

I know that i can have all the style using the method attribute

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

var imageAux;

function initialize() {

 $(".imagePanel").click(function () {

    var aux = $(this);

    if (imageSelected != aux) {

        if (imageSelected != null) {

            imageSelected.stop(true, true).data('selected', false);
            imageSelected.css('border', '0 none');
            imageSelected.css('opacity', '1');
        }

        aux.css('border', '2px solid black').data('selected', true);
        imageSelected = aux;

        //pass the value to me aux variable
        imageAux = imageSelected;
    }

});

function manageAccordion() {

    var imagePath = imageAux.attr("style");
}
```

**I tried something like this but it doesn't work**

`imageAux.attr("style").find('background-image')`

`imageAux.attr("style background image"`

i need a selector that give's me the background image of the div that i already have save in my variable imageAux

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [jQuery.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function

```
imageAux.css('background-image');
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `.attr()` you may have multiple values in the requested attribute. For example, if you have the following div, you will have multiple class names (in this case, 'class1 class2'):

```
<div class="class1 class2"></div>
```

If you are looking for a specific CSS value, use the [jQuery.css method](http://api.jquery.com/css).